# Display the contents of a wallet on a website

Tags: viewkey, javascript, view-only

I want to dynamically display the contents of a Monero wallet via a simple HTTP fetch from a web page.

Something like:

```
var walletViewKey = "48732ifhsdjf8w9";
var walletContents = fetch(moneroBlockChain + walletViewKey);
document.getElementByID("wallet").innerText = walletContents
```

Is this possible with any existing client side SDK or something? Ideally I want to do this from just a simple page hosted on github pages, for example.

When I looked at using a monero-javascript SDK, the only options I saw involved creating a brand new wallet on the server. I want someone to be able to simply provide a view key and that's it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which javascript SDK are you referencing and what precisely do you want to display?

Comment: @jtgrassie I was thinking of [monero-javascript](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript) but maybe there is a better one that is more focused on thin client use cases?

I want to display the total monero in the wallet. like `1.45 XMR`

Comment: [monero-javascript](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript) just wraps the daemon and wallet RPC commands (debatably making it easier to call them). You need to use `monero-wallet-rpc` and `monerod` (or a remote node) regardless, as to get the balance you have to scan the blockchain.

Comment: @jtgrassie Yes, I was planning to find a remote node. But is there a way that I can query the remote node from just a client? Like in my original post up top `var walletContents = fetch(remoteNode + '?q=' + walletViewKey);`, would something like this be possible?

Comment: You can't realistically scan the blockchain with JS in the browser, hence you need to use `monero-wallet-rpc` (regardless of whether you use a local or remote node).